# jQueryMobile Listview page transitions only work for the first few elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a list view that can potentially have over a hundred items.  When clicking on any element it takes you to a details page for that element.

This works beautifully.

However, the lovely page transitions only happen for maybe the first 10 elements after then it just navigates back and forth between the pages which is functional, but not consistent.

Does anybody know why it would do this, and how to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you specify page transitions for the detail pages?

Comment: The transition is set on the anchor tag of the parent page. I set the data-transition property.

Comment: you might want to prepare a **small** example with http://jsfiddle.net ...

Answer (score 1):

After looking into it, I learned that jqm cancels any transitions if the page is scrolled past 3x the height of the screen. I've yet to find a workaround for it, but it's by design to keep the page transitions going smoothly.

Comment: yes after scroll is 3x of device height the transition stops to prevent animating a tall page for performance reasons

Answer (score 1):

please find the setting : defaultGetMaxScrollForTransition in main jqm file.
and try changing current value 3 to 5 or 6?

> $.mobile.getScreenHeight() * 3;